# How do I achieve authorization with asp.net-web-api?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-web-api

How do I achieve authorization with asp.net-web-api?
How many difference between asp.net-mvc authorization and asp.net-web-api authorization?

Answer (score 1):

In MVC you can simply add `[Authorize]` above your controller methods or classes to control protected pages. Or to prevent Forgeries you can use `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` at both view and controller.It will uses MachineKeys to evaluate related user. There is no differences between Asp.net Web API and MVC Platform. But some diffrences exist between MVC platform and Web Pages. You can also [employ Authorization in the Web.config file](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx).

- 2 Types of Authorization in Asp.net MVC are:

[1- Role-Based Authorization](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/roles/role-based-authorization-cs)

[2- User-Based Authorization](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/user-based-authorization-cs)

Answer (score 1):

You should first separate the Authorization and Authentication logic. You can perform authentication through a message handler in an hosting agnostic way and authorization through an action filter.

Check out the [PingYourPackage](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/PingYourPackage) project which is a sample ASP.NET Web API application. You can see the [basic authentication message handler](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/PingYourPackage/blob/dev/src/apps/PingYourPackage.API/MessageHandlers/PingYourPackageAuthHandler.cs) there. This handler sets the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` for the request if the request is authenticated.

Also, have a look at the controllers which are applied with `AuthorizaAttribute` to perform authorization. The `AuthorizaAttribute` inspects the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to perform the authorization.